# How to change the title of the modern style apps in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, title-bar

I'm trying to change some app titles in Windows 8.

Old-designed apps like Firefox or Notepad can be changed easily by the [Window Title Changer](https://www.murgee.com/window-title-changer/) or the [WinSetTitle](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSetTitle.htm#Example) command of AutoHotKey:

```
^j::
   WinSetTitle, Untitled - Notepad, , This is a new title
Return
```

However, modern-desinged apps which have different style of title cannot be change. Some of them are OneNote and ManicTime.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I notice that the titles do be changed, but their appearances are not. How to make the change actually appears in these apps?

<sup>FYI: [How to make another running instance of a same program be detected as a different program?](https://superuser.com/q/1285643/301042)</sup>

Comment: This is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/267029) version of the [other question](https://superuser.com/q/1285643/194694), right? I think it should be closed, then.

Comment: not really. I asked this one a year ago. At that time I only need to see the changes in the titles. The new other question doesn't care about how I see them, but how other apps see them

Comment: I've run into other related issues with .NET applications but hadn't seen this one before (I would be interested to see a solution).  I also hadn't seen ManicTime before so tried it out.  What's curious is that if you use AutoHotkey to change the title of ManicTime itself using `WinSetTitle`--since ManicTime is a titile-detecting program, it will actually detect the new title for itself in the program log.  But the new title doesn't print/display in the actual title bar of the program.